# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to print details from database. Here I am fetching data from multiple tables and printing it on at `BillNewAction`s main method for last line it is showing   Exception `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` to resolve this I set `lazy=false` at `<many-to-one name="productDetails" class="iland.hbm.ProductDetails" update="false" insert="false" lazy="false" fetch="join">` in `BillProductDetails.hbm.xml` but this is not resolving this problem.
What change should I make to run it properly.

```
 public Map fetchAll(int start, int pageSize) {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            List<BillDetails> obj = null;
            long count = 0;
            try {
                count = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from BillDetails").uniqueResult();
                String hql = "from BillDetails as bd "
                        + "left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd "
                        + "left join fetch bd.billProductDetailses as bpd "
                        + "left join fetch bpd.productDetails";
                Query query = session.createQuery(hql).setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(pageSize);
                obj = query.list();
                tx.commit();

            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                if (tx != null) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    tx.rollback();
                }
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
            Map data = new HashMap();
            data.put("list", obj);
            data.put("count", count);
            return data;
        }
```

Printing the details

```
public class BillNewAction{
     public static void main(String[] s) {
            BillDAO dao = new BillDAO();
            Map m = dao.fetchAll(0, 10);

            List<BillDetails> billList = (List<BillDetails>) m.get("list");
            for (BillDetails d : billList) {
                System.out.println("bill no "+d.getBillNo() + "  paymentType " + d.getPaymentType());
                System.out.println("name "+d.getCustomerDetails().getName() + " address " + d.getCustomerDetails().getAddress() + " dob "
                        + d.getCustomerDetails().getDob() + "  anni " + d.getCustomerDetails().getAnniversery());
                List<BillProductDetails> bpd = d.getBillProductDetailses();
                System.out.println("bpd size is " + bpd.size());
                for (BillProductDetails cd : bpd) {
                    System.out.println("qty "+cd.getQty() + " sp " + cd.getSellingPrice() + " up " + cd.getUnitPrice());//Throwing nullPointer Exception
          /*Line 152*/          System.out.println(" barcode "+cd.getProductDetails().getBarcode() + "prType " + cd.getProductDetails().getProductTypes());

                }
            }

        }
}
```

POJO's

```
public class BillDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long billNo;
    private CustomerDetails customerDetails;
    private Float subTotal;
    private Float vat;
    private Float total;
    private String paymentType;
    private String status;
    private Date addDate;
    private List billProductDetailses = new ArrayList();
 //getter and setter
}
public class BillProductDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private BillProductDetailsId id;
     private ProductDetails productDetails;
     private BillDetails billDetails;
     private long qty;
     private float unitPrice;
     private float sellingPrice;
     private Integer discountPercent;
    //getter and setter
}
public class ProductDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Long barcode;
     private ProductBrand productBrand;
     private Sizes sizes;
     private ProductModelDetails productModelDetails;
     private SupplierDetails supplierDetails;
     private Colors colors;
     private ProductTypes productTypes;
     private long quntity;
     private float unitPrice;
     private float sellingPrice;
     private Integer discountPercent;
     private Date addDate;
     private String status;
     private Set billProductDetailses = new HashSet(0);
//getter and setter
}
```

BillDetails.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="iland.hbm.BillDetails" table="bill_details" catalog="retail_shop">
        <id name="billNo" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="bill_no" />
            <generator class="identity"></generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="customerDetails" class="iland.hbm.CustomerDetails" fetch="join">
            <column name="customer_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="subTotal" type="java.lang.Float">
            <column name="sub_total" precision="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="vat" type="java.lang.Float">
            <column name="vat" precision="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="total" type="java.lang.Float">
            <column name="total" precision="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="paymentType" type="string">
            <column name="payment_type" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="status" type="string">
            <column name="status" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="addDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="add_date" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="billProductDetailses" table="bill_product_details" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join">
            <key>
                <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="iland.hbm.BillProductDetails" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

BillProductDetails.hbm.xml

```
hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="iland.hbm.BillProductDetails" table="bill_product_details" catalog="retail_shop">
        <composite-id name="id" class="iland.hbm.BillProductDetailsId">
            <key-property name="productId" type="long">
                <column name="product_id" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="billNo" type="long">
                <column name="bill_no" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="productDetails" class="iland.hbm.ProductDetails" update="false" insert="false" lazy="false" fetch="join">
            <column name="product_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="billDetails" class="iland.hbm.BillDetails" update="false" insert="false" fetch="join">
            <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="qty" type="long">
            <column name="qty" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="unitPrice" type="float">
            <column name="unit_price" precision="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="sellingPrice" type="float">
            <column name="selling_price" precision="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="discountPercent" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="discount_percent" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at iland.hbm.ProductTypes_$$_javassist_7.toString(ProductTypes_$$_javassist_7.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at iland.bill.BillNewAction.main(BillNewAction.java:152)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Can you post the `ProductTypes` class, that's where your exception is coming from.

Comment: There's no fetch in the query for the product types, so it's not initialised at time of query.

Comment: @wds please see updated query. insted ob billdetails it is `productDetails`

Comment: @JamesMassey How you got that exception is at `ProductTypes`

Comment: `at iland.hbm.ProductTypes_$$_javassist_7.toString(ProductTypes_$$_javassist_7.java)` clearly points to your ProductTypes object. Am I right in guessing that its an enum? Also, the only other thing is that on line 152 you are getting a `Long` and as the `Long` class is not a collection object, it can't be causing this exception.

Comment: @JamesMassey My `ProductDetails` Pojo is `public class ProductDetails implements java.io.Serializable {
 .. 
    private Long id;
    private String barcode;
    private ProductTypes productTypes;}` I set `lazy="false"` for `ProductTypes` in my hbm file now working perfectly.